# Where can I find a working winnt.h? Rubenvb's appears to be very wrong

Tags: c++, windows, ming

Looking thru the definitions in winnt.h from rubenvb's 4.7.2 download (c++.exe --version is rubenvb-4.7.2-release) reveals a number of routines with inline assembly that simply don't work correctly.  At least they don't on my i7 processor (could these have been coded for some other processor?).

However, given the nature of how gcc is developed, it seems possible that some other implementation has done a better job with this file.

So, 2 questions:

1. Does anyone know where to find a better winnt.h?
2. Failing that, does anyone know how to contact reubanvb?

Comment: I generally use http://nuwen.net/mingw.html. Might want to wait a bit for GCC 4.8.0, though.

Comment: @chris: AFAIK the nuwen distribution is 32-bit only, like the main MinGW distribution. rubenvb's build, as I recall, is of MinGW-64, presumably with both 32-bit and 64-bit compiler.

Comment: @david: could you give an **example**

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Good point, that comes in handy :p

Comment: @david: also re your point 2, ruben is often in the C++ Lounge chatroom here on SO. well unless i'm conflating two similar identities

Comment: Well, I just downloaded nuwen, and there is a winnt.h.  However, it doesn't have any of the definitions I was looking for: bitscanforward, bittest, etc.

Comment: @Alf For examples, see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15532980/2189500](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15532980/2189500)

Comment: @alf Thanks for the tip.  Apparently ruben hasn't been to that chat room today, but I'll keep checking.  BTW, if you want more examples, _bittest is also wrong.  When the first 5 I checked were all wrong, the rest were all suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with the Mingw-w64 team to update the asm routines in winnt.h (and other headers).  To the best of my knowledge, they are all correct now.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows SDK is a free download. You can get the one for Windows 8 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx), or use [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) to stick with targeting Windows 7. Naturally, it includes all of the headers necessary to call Windows functions, including `WinNT.h`.

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't be. It is the only way to develop Windows applications, so if MinGW supports developing Windows applications, it will have to support the Windows SDK. MinGW is just a C++ compiler.

Comment: @cody I think you have missed the point.  The original post made reference to "a number of routines with inline assembly."  This is (part of) gcc's answer to intrinsics.  The "#pragma intrinsic(_BitScanForward)" in the WSDK's winnt.h is completely ignored by gcc.  The answer appears to be work with the developers at sourceforge to get these routines repaired, which is what I am doing.  They are receptive, but it has been slow going.

Comment: Guess so. Seemed like a weird question. If there's a bug in code you're getting from a particular vendor, you should contact that vendor for support. I assumed you wanted to know "where to find a better winnt.h", and so I answered that question.